# Incremental and Snapshot both displayed for single job

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

We have a build that shows Snapshot in the History tab, but then shows Job can run incrementally when viewing Spark details of the job. Are these ideas necessarily contradicting? If so, which one is correct?

I expected the History tab and Spark details page to align on whether the job ran incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

The job could be processing the inputs incrementally (i.e. taking just the changes since the last time it built) and writing the output as a snapshot (i.e. replacing the whole dataset).

The history tab would only show you what type of transaction was applied to the output dataset.